# Smoke Domains in Blender

Tags: physics

When doing the fire simulation within Blender Render can the smoke domain be anything other than a cube, such as sphere or other mesh?

Comment: You could always try it and see.. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a mesh besides the cube as a smoke domain. I would however always stick to a boxes because Blender smoke simulators uses voxels (small cubes). And  other meshes can cause unpredictable behaviors, although I believe this has improved in recent GSOC. When using other meshes, depending on the smoke simulation's resolution the smoke might b outside of the domain.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use the collision mesh inside domain cube 
and the smoke mesh inside the collision mesh than play with settings
it will give you nice result

[image]

[image]