# Why isn't smoke flowing with the shape of the domain?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I created this Smoke domain.

[image: Smoke Domain]

Then When I added smoke, it didn't stay within the domain, it went through the hole.

[image: Error]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZzhZ.png

Comment: A domain is only a cube. You can add an invisible square collision mesh though

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7260/smoke-domains-in-blender/47873#47873 and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12181/how-to-simulate-a-gas/12185#12185

Answer (score 11):

## The smoke domain can only be a cube or a Cuboid.

Form the [blender manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/smoke/types/domain.html?highlight=smoke)

> You can use other shapes of mesh objects as domain objects, but the smoke simulator will use the shape’s bounding box as the domain bounds. In other words, the actual shape of the domain will still be rectangular.

To have the smoke flow around, you would need to add another object and set it as **[smoke collision](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/smoke/types/collisions.html)**.

> Smoke Collision objects are used to deflect smoke and influence airflow.

[image]

See this answer:[What Are the Differences between Smoke Collision Types?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1723/what-are-the-differences-between-smoke-collision-types)

To have the smoke be contained by Collision objects, place the smoke emitters inside them.

[image]

In this example a text object has been converted to mesh, set as smoke collision and placed within the smoke domain.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But this was just an example, actually, I have some text, I turned it into a Mesh and made it a smoke domain. I hope you can understated my problem.

Comment: Same thing. The domain is calculated as a bounding box.  Please edit your question and put on it what you really want to accomplish.

Comment: I want turn some text into a smoke domain.

Comment: @AbhaGupta You can't do that. The domain will always behave like a cube. Yo need to set the text as collision object, and set the smoke emitters inside the text. See updated answer

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but it doesn't work. I'm sure your answer is right, but I am doing some mistake. Please help me.

Comment: I first deleted the cube, then added the text, converted it into a mesh, set it  as smoke collision, then I added it into a cube and set that as smoke domain, and finally I made small cubes and put it inside the individual letters. But it doesn't work.It goes around the text.

Comment: It does take a lot of playing around with the settings, most importantly the smoke resolution on the domain. Please take a look at the supplied blend file on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding loop cuts to the domain and shape it as you like. I added 2 loop cuts to a cube and scale the loop cuts and don't use adaptive domain and it follow the shape I wanted. I never tried a rectanguakr shape but it might as well work...

Comment: Can you show example (or share the blend file)? It seems to me you felt into some mistake ... Thank you