# How do I make smoke fill a specific object

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How do I make it so that smoke only fits a specific object like a cube or sphere so the smoke makes the shape of the object.

Let's say I have a single object of a hat and what I want to do is make the smoke in the shape of the hat.

Help

Comment: Use a particle system and set it up and at the end make the particle system to be the smoke/fire.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has been asked previously here:

[Why isn't smoke flowing with the shape of the domain?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51964/why-isnt-smoke-flowing-with-the-shape-of-the-domain)

Basically - use a cube as usual as your smoke domain, and within that add your hollow hat-shaped object, make it a 'collision' object in the physics properties, and place your smoke emitters within that object.